# What's the point of keeping a merged question with deleted target?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question

[Want name only to appear after signing into gmail account, not my email address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13974/want-name-only-to-appear-after-signing-into-gmail-account-not-my-email-address) is locked:

> merged by phwd♦ Mar 30 '11 at 2:36
>
> This question was merged with Display name instead of email address when logging into Gmail because it is an exact duplicate of that question.
>
> migrated from webmasters.stackexchange.com Mar 29 '11 at 18:24
>
> This question came from our site for pro webmasters.

For six years it has remained visible on WA yet won't accept votes (up/down/Close). Neither Comment nor Answer may be added. It is, we are told, exactly the same as a Q that has been deleted.

Why is this retained?

---

The above even features under "Here are some similar questions that might be relevant":

[image: Page Not Found]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was merged into the other question which is now deleted. Have deleted the merge stub as well